# JSP Getting 2 variables from one option value

Tags: java, jsp, html-select

I have a form that prints out the name of a food and price from a database

```
<select name="food" multiple="multiple" size="10" >
    <% for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i) {
    %>
    <option 
        value="<%out.println(name.get(i));%>">
        <% out.println(name.get(i) + "-------- $" + price.get(i));%>
    </option> 
    <%
        }
    %>
</select>
```

Which gives me the food and price when i put it into an array

```
 String[] list = request.getParameterValues("food");`foodarray = list;
 application.setAttribute("sessfood", foodarray);
```

I am using

```
String[] ceiArray =  (String[])application.getAttribute("sessfood");
```

to get the names from the previous jsp page. So, I can retrieve it to an other webpage but it only returns the name not the price is there anyway I can also retrieve the price also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, use of *`<% scriptlets %>`* is deprecated in JSPs so consider switching to JSP EL. I've used the same to show how simple its use is.

To retrieve `price` in the other JSP, you have to pass it too. Currently, your `<select>` displays both `name` and `price`, but passes `name` only. So, the JSP code should look like

```
<c:set var="names" value="<%= name %>" />
<c:set var="prices" value="<%= price %>" />

<select name="food" multiple="multiple" size="10" >
  <c:forEach items="${names}" var="name" varStatus="loop">
    <option value="${name}=${prices[loop.index]}">
        ${name}-------- $${prices[loop.index]}
    </option> 
  </c:forEach>
</select>
```

In your target servlet you can retrieve the *name=price* mappings and store it in whicever way is more convenient for your JSP to retrive the values from. I'm storing the values in a `Map` here.

```
String[] selection = request.getParameterValues("food");

Map<String, String> foodPrices = new HashMap<String, String>(selection.length);
for (String option: selection) {
    String[] foodPrice = option.split("=");
    foodPrices.put(foodPrice[0], foodPrice[1]);
}

application.setAttribute("foodMap", foodPrices);
```

Now, in your JSP you can access the prices as

```
<c:forEach items="${foodMap}" var="entry">
    <li>Price of ${entry.key} = $${entry.value}</li>
</c:forEach>
```

By the way, I'm not sure if you should store the user's food selection into `application` scope as its shared by all the users of your application. If that's not what you intended, use the `session` scope instead.

Answer (score 0):

Think of food as a domain object, that is, it represents part of your problem domain. Food has properties, name, price, etc. - since it has a price, maybe it would be better called a Product.

Over time, the name or price may change, so you should assign a unique code to your Product to identify it over time. It is this unique code that should be used for your value in the form. Then you can use the code to lookup the Product domain object to access the other properties, such as price.

As an aside, since the code uniquely identifies your domain object, it should also be used in your `equals` and `hashCode` methods to ensure that 2 instances representing the same domain object behave properly.